# Different behavior between pytorch.cdist and a self-made distance function between pair of points

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

For a loss I had to compute the distance between each pair of points in a point cloud. I did it using the following method in a first time (x is a tensor of shape (Batch, nb_points, 3)):

`dist = (x.unsqueeze(1) - x.unsqueeze(2)).pow(2).sum(-1).sqrt()`

Giving a tensor dist of shape (nb_points, nb_points, 3).
Using this implementation gave a float value in the loss but NaNs after back-propagation.

I replaced it by :
`dist = torch.cdist(x,x)`
and it worked properly.

My question is, why is it working in one case and not the other, is there anything different between my implementation and cdist? Is it related to gradients computation?

I expected the two implementation to have a similar behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.